# Detect if html parent is hidden

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to detect when a specific HTML element on the page becomes hidden. This usually happens due to a parent element (maybe few levels up) becoming hidden. Is there a simple way to detect this. Or do I need to traverse the DOM and check each parent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$(foo).is(":hidden")
```

can figure that out for you in current jQuery versions.

Answer (score 9):

You can just check if it's [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), for example:

```
$(".selector:hidden").length > 0
//or
$(".selector").is(":hidden")
```

This works if the parent is hidden, or any parent, or the element directly...as long as the element itself has no dimensions, it's [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```js
alert($('#test1').is(":visible"));
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div id="test1">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EVrM/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses offsetHeight.  That works in most browsers.  But you can check that without jQuery too.